# javascript adding select and checkbox values/// getting negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I need to be able to have the user pick a billing term from a select drop down and then choose checkboxes to add to the total. It seems to work relatively well on JSFIDDLE however on my site, there are some cases where selecting all the checkboxes and then resetting the total to 0 by selecting 'Choose billing term' then unchecking all the options will result in negative numbers. Does anyone have any suggestions? Even checking and unchecking options will start to get negative numbers.

HTML:

```
<div class="payment-term">
  <label>Billing period:</label>
  <select id="billing-price" name="billing-term" class="selectpicker">
    <option value="0">Choose billing term</option>
    <option value="300">12 Months: $300/mo. (Save 20%)</option>
    <option value="350">1 Month: $350/mo.</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <label>Extra Features ($50/month): </label>
</div>

<section id="extra-features">
  <div class="span3">
    <label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Instagram
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Review site monitoring
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Google+
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> LinkedIn
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Pinterest
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> FourSquare
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Tumblr
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sum" value="50" data-toggle="checkbox"> Advertising
    </label>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="card-charge-info">
  Your card will be charged $<span id="payment-total">0</span> now, and your subscription will bill $<span id="payment-rebill">0</span> every month thereafter. You can cancel or change plans anytime.
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
var select = document.getElementById('billing-price');
select.addEventListener('change', updatePrice, false);
var price = 0;
var additional = 0;

function updatePrice(e) {
    price = parseFloat(select.value);
    document.getElementById('payment-total').innerText = price + additional;
    if (price == select.options[2].value){
    document.getElementById('payment-rebill').innerText = 0 + additional; 
    } else {
    document.getElementById('payment-rebill').innerText = price + additional;
    }
}
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');
    total2 = document.getElementById('payment-rebill');

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        additional += add
        total.innerHTML = price + additional
        total2.innerHTML = price + additional
    }
}
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uZbee/2/ 
My site (not working correctly): http://thesomii.com/getstarted/basic/

I am using a javascript file for my checkboxes to give them a better appearance. I fear it maybe effecting my javascript code for the sum of checked boxes.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `this.checked` is always false except for the first time you check the box. Maybe the flatui-checkbox.js affects this? You're not loading it in the fiddle.

Comment: The line `total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');` should end with a `,`, not a `;`. Currently `total2` is an implicit global. Using http://jshint.com/ or http://jslint.com/ can help spot these types of errors.

Comment: It appears that you are only calculating the total cost on the client-side, none of the checkboxes have unique names that can be verified on the back-end. This is a [very bad idea](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Validation_performed_in_client), and could lead to losing a lot of money. It would be [trivial to change](http://www.phpied.com/when-client-only-validation-is-good-for-business/) the value attribute to any price I wanted on the client side before submitting the form.

Comment: @UselessCode I have not done any back-end on the site. I am simply trying to get the front-end functional. Thanks for looking out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative value is caused by the input is not checked, so the `this.checked` in this line

```
var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
```

is always false, resulting the added value is negative.

Change `this.checked` to `this.parentNode.className.split(" ").indexOf("checked") > -1` may help.

```
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = this.value * (this.parentNode.className.split(" ").indexOf("checked") > -1 ? 1 : -1);
        additional += add
        total.innerHTML = price + additional
        total2.innerHTML = price + additional
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that class name related to the flatui-checkbox.js library?

Comment: Yeah, seems like the library create <label> element as the input's parent, and the <label> has "checked" class name

Comment: But the real issue is that the library apparently overrides the changes to the checkbox element itself. The first time you check the box, `this.checked` is true, but when you check it again later, it's false.